# Page is not working -- ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

When this code implement in codeigniter  (this type of error show => localhost redirected you too many times.)

1)application/config/config.php

```
    $config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

2)application/config/hooks.php

```
    $hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
        'function' => 'checkAdminLogin',
        'filename' => 'authenticate_login.php',
        'filepath' => 'hooks',
    );
```

3)application/hooks/authenticate_login.php  (make new php file (authenticate_login.php))

```
    function checkAdminLogin() {
        $CI = & get_instance();
        if (!getSession('is_logged_in')) {
            redirect('admin/login');
        } else
            return true;
    }

    function getSession($key) {
        $CI = & get_instance();
        return $CI->session->userdata(trim($key));
    }
```

Comment: What are the meanings of 1) and 2) in the code?

Comment: On the login page you have a redirect loop

Comment: I have mention steps like 1, 2, 3 etc...

Comment: can you show the code of `admin/login`

Comment: admin folder name
login controller name
function index() {
die("hello");
}

Answer (score 1):

When your visitor goes to admin/login your code will detect that he is not logged in and redirect it again to admin/login....and over, and over again...

You must detect login page route and not redirect from it.

Something like:

```
function checkAdminLogin() {
    $CI = & get_instance();
    if (!getSession('is_logged_in'))
    {
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!='/admin/login') {
            redirect('admin/login');
        }else{
            // User is on login page, don't redirect him again
        }
    } else
        return true;
}
```

But I'm not sure what returning true means in your case. Basically you have 3 cases here:

1. Logged in
2. Not logged in, but on login page
3. Not logged in and not on login page

So you have to think of all those 3.

Comment: what is a solution ??

Comment: Inside checkAdminLogin() do redirection only if you are not already on login page. You have to check what's current page url there.